# Something wrong with Emacs shell

Tags: emacs

I use Ubuntu8.10 and emacs-snapshot. Running shell-mode on emacs and input "ls" shows escape codes:

[screenshot http://lh3.ggpht.com/_os_zrveP8Ns/SdMmohKNjmI/AAAAAAAADB4/VlKpr5H_7ZA/s512/screen.png](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_os_zrveP8Ns/SdMmohKNjmI/AAAAAAAADB4/VlKpr5H_7ZA/s512/screen.png)

How can I get the output I expect?

Comment: Well, those funny characters are escape sequences ('ESC' '[' '0' 'm') which can serve a s a clue to others, but I won't answer since I don't know a specific fix.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use [AnsiTerm](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTerm) which does support colors or you can enable [AnsiColor](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiColor) for the normal shell:

```
(autoload 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on "ansi-color" nil t)
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
```

Comment: Note that in order for this to have any effect, `ansi-color-process-output` must be in `comint-output-filter-functions`.

Answer (score 5):

Furthermore, you may choose another shell:  `M-x term` or `M-x eshell`. The former provides an interface that is much closer to a real terminal emulator than `shell-mode` (once you start it, you can get out of the mode with `C-c C-j` and get in again with `C-c C-k`). The latter is a shell implementation written in Elisp (you can use the common shell commands as well as evaluating Lisp code).

Comment: I know eshell, but I don't like it, not that powerful.

Comment: You are saying a general purpose programing langauge is less powerful than *shell*?  I think you just don't know how to use it.

Comment: I do not mean that. It is not about any languages versus shell, but the `shell-mode` and its alternatives. If you want a shell inside Emacs, I found myself `term-mode` much convenient, which allows the buffer to behave like a real terminal or you can work on it as any other common Emacs buffer.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on [vatine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34771/vatine)'s answer, you can add that inside your .cshrc (.tcshrc/.bashrc) wrapped with a check for the environment variable [INSIDE_EMACS](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interactive-Shell.html).

For example (from my .tcshrc):

```
if ( $?INSIDE_EMACS ) then
   alias l 'ls --color=never'
endif
```

Comment: For `sh` and compatibles, `test "$INSIDE_EMACS" && alias l='ls --color=never'` though you might want to use a function instead of an alias.

Answer (score 2):

M-x ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "l" is trying to colorise the output and emacs isn't having any of it. Try the following:

```
$ unalias l
$ alias l ls --color=never
```

Comment: how to only change it in emacs?

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped my `alias ls ='ls --color=auto'` in ~/.bashrc:

```
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
        alias ls='ls --color=auto'
        ...
    fi
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

This disables using `color=auto` in emacs.